# How to connect spring boot backend with frontend?

Tags: java, spring-boot, frontend

I can develop a simple REST apllication (CRUD operations, for example) on Spring Boot, but how to connect it with HTML pages. I have already used Freemarker + Bootstrap. But the options are limited, when it concerns the design part.
What is the next step? What technologies or platform should I use?

Comment: [*Vaadin Flow*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow_(Java_API))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add annotation @CrossOrigin in your controller. It is enough for very little application but it is better to create special configuration for this.

You create a package configuration on the same level src/main in java/(your project name). In this package, you create a class WebConfig:

```
package yourProject.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    

    @Value("${project.cors.allowed-origins}")
    private String[] allowedOrigins;

    @Value("${project.cors.allowed-methods}")
    private String[] allowedMethods;
    
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);

    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins).allowedMethods(allowedMethods);
    }
```

And in application.properties you add origin of your front (in my case it is vue application)  and methods:

```
# Cors properties:

project.cors.allowed-origins=http://localhost:5173
project.cors.allowed-methods=POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RESTful APIs. for that,

1. Create a RESTful API in your Spring Boot application.
2. Create a frontend that can consume the RESTful API.

To create a RESTful API in your Spring Boot application, you can use the Spring MVC framework.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).